# Questions on Erdős–Ginzburg–Ziv theorem for primes and understanding related lemmas and their applications.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, additive-combinatorics, arithmetic-combinatorics

While trying to prove the prime case of  [Erdős–Ginzburg–Ziv theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Erd%C3%B6s-Ginzburg-Ziv_theorem):

> **Theorem:** *For every prime number $p$, in any set of $2p-1$ integers, the sum $p$ of them divisible by $p$.*

I came across with the following lemma:

> **Lemma 1:** If $p$ is a prime number and $A,B$
>    are subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $\varnothing\neq A\neq \mathbb{Z}_p
>  $ and $\left |B\right | =2$, then $\left |A+B \right | \geq\left
>  |A\right |+1  $, where $ A+B=\{a+b: a \in A, b \in B \} $.

**Proof:** Without loss of generality $B=\{ 0,\beta\}$, where $\beta \neq 0$ and then $A\subseteq A+B$. Let us assume by contradiction that $A+B=A$. Let $a\in A$. Therefore $a+\beta\in A+B$, and thus $a+\beta\in A$. By this manner we can deduce that $a+k\beta\in A$ for every $k$ and from here that

$$\mathbb{Z}_p=\{a,a+\beta, a+2\beta,\dots , a+(p-1)\beta\}\subseteq A $$

But we assume $A\neq \mathbb{Z}_p$.■

**Question 1:** How we deduce that  $\left |A+B \right | \geq\left |A\right |+1$ by such contradiction?

Here I decided to prove this lemma by my own, and I came up with some more general result:

> **Lemma 2:** If $p$ is a prime number and $A,B$ are subsets of
>    $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $\varnothing\neq A,B$, then $\left |A+B \right |
>  \geq\left |A\right |+\left |B\right | -1 $

**Proof:** Since the set of integer numbers is ordered set, we can translate $A$ and $B$ to new sets $A'$ and $B'$, so that $\sup(A')=0$ and $\inf(B')=0$ and still preserve the cardinalities of these two sets, thus $\left |A\right|=\left |A'\right |$ and $\left |B\right|=\left |B'\right |$. Now, since $0\in A',B'$ we can deduce that $A\cup B\subseteq A+B$. Small observation about the nature of $A'$ and $B'$ revivals that $\left |A\cup B\right|=\left |A\right|+\left |B\right|-1$. Combining the last result with $\left |A\cup B\right|\leq\left |A+B\right |$ we get the desired result. ■

Now, returning to text where lemma 1 is used,

**Proof(EGZ for primes):** Without loss of generality let

$$(1) \ \  \ \ \ \ \      0\leq a_1\leq a_2\leq\dots \leq a_{2p-1}<p$$

If $a_i=a_{i+p-1}$ for certain $1\leq i\leq p$, then

$$\sum^{i+p-1}_{j=i}=pa_i$$

And that is what we looked for.

Now suppose that $a_i\neq a_{i+p-1}$ for all $1\leq i\leq p$, then we define $A_1=\{ a_1\}$ and $A_i=\{a_i,a_{i+p-1}\}$for $1\leq i\leq p $, then by repeating the lemma above one can conclude that in $\mathbb{Z}_p$:

$$\left|A_1+A_2+\cdots +A_p \right|=p$$

Thus, every element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the sum of exact $p$ terms of our ordered set, and that the sum of $p$ elements of that set divisible by $p$. 
■

**Question 2:** How really one can deduce $\left|A_1+A_2+\cdots +A_p \right|=p$ from the lemma, and how can one conclude that every element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the sum of exact $p$ terms of our ordered set, and that the sum of $p$ elements of that set divisible by $p$?

Searching for more information, I came up with [Noga Alon and Moshe Duniner article](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/egz1.pdf#page=3&zoom=auto,-134,510), which proved EGZ theorem in five different ways. The first proof that they begin with is the related one. They states the Cauchy-Davenport theorem:

> **Cauchy-Davenport theorem:** If $p$ is a prime number and $A,B$ are two nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $\left | A+B  \right|\geq \min\{p,\left|A  \right|+ \left | B \right |-1 \}$

And proving in the same matter the prime case of EGZ.

**Question 3:** Do we really need the Cauchy-Davenport theorem to prove EGZ theorem for primes?

Thank you.

Comment: Your proof of Lemma 2 seems wrong. Taking modulo p we would get $A \cup B \leq |A| + |B| - 1$, and not equal to. Note that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. And you are treating them as subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ and then arguing about cardinalities.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: From the contradiction we get that $A$ is a proper subset of $A + B$ and hence $|A + B| > |A|$, or equivalently, $|A + B| \geq |A| + 1$.

Question 2: We should define $A_1 = \{a_1, a_{p - 1}\}$. Then by an induction argument that has the following crucial part $|A_1 + \dots + A_{i + 1}| \geq |A_1 + \dots + A_i| + |A_{i + 1}| - 1 \geq \min \{p, i + 1\}$, implies that $|A_1 + \dots + A_p| \geq \min \{p, p + 1\} = p$.

Question 3: No, we do not need Cauchy-Davenport to prove EGZ. As Alon-Dubiner have showed, it can be proved in several ways not all of which require Cauchy-Davenport. One of the most recent proofs of EGZ is that involving Restricted Variable Chevalley-Warning theorem, which follows from a result of Alon-Furedi: http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7793, http://www.davidbrink.dk/Chevalley.pdf.

Here's the argument. Let $f= \sum x_i$ and $g = \sum a_ix_i$, where $a_i$'s are the $2p−1$ numbers modulo $p$. Then $(1−f^{p−1})(1−g^{p−1})$ has degree $2p−2$ and hence at least one non-zero $e = (e_1, \dots, e_{2p-1}) \in \{0,1\}^{2p−1} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_p^{2p - 1}$ besides the origin, which corresponds to a common zero of $f$ and $g$. This non-zero corresponds to a subsequence of length $p$ (length is insured by the fact that $f(e_1, \dots, e_{2p-1}) = 0$) that sums up to $0$ (this is ensured by the fact that $g(e_1, \dots, e_{2p-1}) = 0$).